# Geometry of $2 \times 2$ matrix mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, conic-sections

Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. I'm interested in the geometry of the mapping $T(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The effect on the vectors $\mathbf{e_1} = (1,0)$ and $\mathbf{e_2} = (0,1)$ is clear -- $T(\mathbf{e_1})$ and $T(\mathbf{e_2})$ are just the columns of $\mathbf{A}$. So, by linearity, a unit square gets mapped to a parallelogram. The green square gets mapped to the pink parallelogram in the pictures below.

Now let's consider the effect on  a unit circle. It gets mapped to an ellipse, and I'm interested in how the geometry of this ellipse is related to the matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

One case seems clear: if $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, then the axes of the ellipse are the eignevectors of $\mathbf{A}$, and its semi-axis lengths are the eigenvalues. The "stretching" of the circle to form the ellipse is nicely related to eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Fabulous. This is illustrated in the following picture:

[image]

Another case is also clear: if the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are not real, then presumably there is no relationship whatsoever to the geometry of the ellipse.

Now the case that's puzzling me: what if $\mathbf{A}$ is not symmetric, but still has real eigenvalues. What sort of geometric relationship exists in this case, if any? This case is illustrated in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant keyword to read about is "singular values". For a map $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, you can always find an **orthonormal basis** $(v_1,v_2)$ of the domain (with respect to the standard Euclidean metric) and an **orthonormal basis** $(w_1,w_2)$ of the range such that $T(v_i) = \sigma_i w_i$ for $\sigma_i \geq 0$. The numbers $\sigma_i$ are called the singular values of $T$ and are the eigenvalues of $\sqrt{T^{*}T}$ or $\sqrt{TT^{*}}$ (in your cases, $\sqrt{A^TA}$ or $\sqrt{AA^T}$).

Since the bases $(v_i),(w_i)$ are orthonormal, this means that assuming $T$ is invertible (and then $\sigma_i > 0$ for all $i$), a unit circle will be mapped to an ellipse whose axes are $w_1,w_2$ of lengths $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ respectively. It $T$ is not invertible, it will map the unit circle to a "circle" of lower dimension.

If $T$ is positive definite, then $T$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, you can get $v_i = w_i$ and the $\sigma_i$ will be the eigenvalues of $T$. If $T$ is symmetric, the singular values will be the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $T$. If $T$ is not symmetric, then the only relation you can expect between the singular values and the eigenvalues is that $\sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2 = |\lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2| = |\det(A)|$. For example, consider the family of matrices

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

The only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$ and if $a \neq 0$ then $A$ is not diagonalizable. The singular values of $A$ are given by

$$ \sigma_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2 + a^2 + a\sqrt{4 + a^2}}{2}}, \sigma_2 = \sqrt{\frac{2 + a^2 - a\sqrt{4 + a^2}}{2}}. $$

They satisfy $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 = 1$ and $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 > 0$ and when $a$ runs in $(0,\infty)$, the singular value $\sigma_1$ runs between $(1,\infty)$ while $\sigma_2 = \frac{1}{\sigma_1}$ runs between $1$ and $0$ so you get all possible pairs of singular values subject to the constraint $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 = 1$. Geometrically, since $\det(A) = 1$, the matrix $A$ must map the unit disc to an ellipse of area $1$. As $\sigma_1 \to \infty$, the matrix $A$ maps the unit disc to an ellipse in which one axis (corresponding to the singular value $\sigma_1$) becomes longer and longer while the second axis becomes shorter and shorter to keep the area of ellipse constant.

Comment: BTW, if $A$ is normal and not symmetric, the eigenvalues of $A$ are purely imaginary and conjugate and $T_A$ will map the unit circle to a circle whose radius is the absolute value of the eigenvalues so in this case, you also get a relation between the eigenvalues and the image of the unit circle.

Comment: Great answer, hit the nail on the head. My one complaint is that "if $T$ is not symmetric, then there is no direct relation between the eigenvalues of $T$ and the singular values of $T$" seems like *too* strong a statement

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yeah, sorry about that. There is an obvious relation (which is the only one that holds generically, at least in the $2 \times 2$ case) and I've edited my answer to reflect that. If you know about any other relations between the eigenvalues and the singular values, I would be interested to hear and have some references.

Comment: And, of course, I'd be interested, too.

Comment: Since the singular values $\sigma_i$ are eigenvalues of $\sqrt{AA^T}$, I'd expect them to be somehow related to the eigenvalues  $\lambda_i$ of $A$. But maybe the relationship is too complicated to provide any insight. What if we express eigenvectors in polar coordinates? Does that lead anywhere?

Comment: @bubba: My example which you can easily generalize to the case of two distinct eigenvalues shows that there is in general no relation other than $\sigma_1 \sigma_1 = |\lambda_1 \lambda_2|$. The singular values can be arbitrary large or arbitrary small with respect to the eigenvalues as long as the relation above holds.

Comment: @levap Bhatia's matrix analysis has a lot on the way the two are related; there's apparently a nice characterization for when a tuple of eigenvalues and a tuple of singular values could correspond to the same matrix.  Note that the characterization is with *inequalities*, so there's a bit of wiggle room; it's not the case that one could deduce one from the other.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Very nice, thanks!